# how to convert timestamp to date in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i am working on aggregation of mongodb collection.my mongodb collection has creation_time in timestamp.How will i can collect same day result and aggregate with next day result.Suppose i have to collect data for 5 days.My mongodb collection is:

```
{
    "_id" : "1522845653126"
},
{
    "_id" : "1522838153324"
},
{
    "_id" : "1513421466415"
},
{
    "_id" : "1515488183153"
},
{
    "_id" : "1521571234500"
}
```

How can i calculate.How many entry are save on specific date?? nd  suppose I want is to query results that returns a running total of the aggregation, like:

```
{
 time: "2013-10-10"
 count: 3,

},
{
 time: "2013-10-11"
 total: 7,

}
```

something like this.
i have tried to do something like this

```
db.coll.aggregate([
   {
        $group:{
        _id:new Date($creation_time).toLocaleDateString(),
         $count:{$add:1}
            }
         time:new Date($creation_time).toLocaleDateString()
   }
 ])
```

It does not work.where am i doing wrong??I am new to mongodb.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 20):

You can use [**`$toDate`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) aggregation to convert timestamp to ISO date and [**`$toLong`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) to convert string timestamp to integer value in **mongodb 3.6**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": {
      "$toDate": {
        "$toLong": "$_id"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$_id" } },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Try it [**here**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xQiCK-qxshO)

**And with the previous versions**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "date": { "$add": [ new Date(0), "$_id" ] }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Good to know, but it support MongoDB 4.0+ only…

Comment: @YongweiWu In previous version you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889949/mongo-groupby-month-using-unix-millisecond-time/51890009#51890009

Comment: Can we change timezone in add

Comment: ObjectId() is not a timestamp.  It has a datetime encoded and embedded but the MongoDB BSON typespec for timestamp is the number of seconds since Linux Epoch.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/ for more info

Answer (score 3):

In my case ,
I used

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "date": { "$toDate": { 
        $multiply:["$_id",1000 ]
             } 
       }
  }}
])
```

convert timestamp  from milliseconds to seconds.