# Mongo groupby month using UNIX millisecond time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo collection that looks as follows:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    timestamp: 1534488870841,
    type: 'deposit'
}, {
    id: 1,
    timestamp: 1534488915119,
    type: 'deposit'
}]
```

How can I make a query to list all `deposit` transactions, grouped by the month.

The month must be calculated using the `timestamp` attribute (UNIX millisecond).

I can get the deposit's as follows but I am unsure on how to group:

```
db.getCollection('transactions').find(
{"type":"deposit"});
```

**Edit**: Mongo version 3.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in mongodb **4.0**

You can convert `timestamp` to date using [**`$toDate`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) aggregation and then [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)  with [**`$month`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/)  aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "type": "deposits" }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "date": {
      "$toDate": "$timestamp"
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$month": "$date" },
    "deposits": {
      "$push": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }}
])
```

You can try below aggregation in mongodb **3.4**

In **3.4** you can convert `timestamp` to date by adding `new Date()` in it and [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) it by using [**`$dateToString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "type": "deposits" }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "date": {
      "$add": [ new Date(0), "$timestamp" ]
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$dateToString": {
        "format": "%m",
        "date": "$date"
      }
    },
    "deposits": {
      "$push": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Hey, sorry but I am using Mongo 3.4

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you tell me where you defined `deposits`? Because I have other types of transactions in my collection as well. How can I combine it with the partial answer I have already mentioned in the question?

Comment: You can put the `{ $match: { type: "deposits" }}` at the starting stage before `$addFields`... Updated the answer as well

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Would it be possible to add the count under each month as well?

Comment: replace `$group` stage with this `{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$dateToString": {
        "format": "%m",
        "date": "$date"
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "deposits": {
      "$push": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }}`