# Categorise data according to date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection which kinda looks like this

```
const TransactionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  transactionType: {
    type: String,
    enum: [transactionTypes.TRANSACTION_EXPENSE, transactionTypes.TRANSACTION_INCOME],
    required: true
  },
  amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  paymentType: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      transactionPaymentTypes.PAYMENT_CARD,
      transactionPaymentTypes.PAYMENT_CASH
    ],
    required: true
  },
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  description: String,
  tags: [String]
});
```

This represents a transaction between two users.
What I want to do is to categorise data per date.

So If I have three transactions for 15-05-2018, and four transactions for 16-05-2018, I want to group them like

```
[
{
date: "15-05-2018",
transactions: [Transaction]
},
{
date: "16-05-2018",
transactions: [Transaction]
}
]
```

PS. I have written 15-05-2018 just for convenience. Realistically the data will be a timestamp.

How can make this work?

I googled around and I found that we should use the aggregate functionality of mongoose/mongodb, but I couldn't understand how to make it work.

NOTE:
I'm using NodeJS, ExpressJS and MongoDB with Mongoose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo groupby month using UNIX millisecond time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889949/mongo-groupby-month-using-unix-millisecond-time)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use the aggregation framework to address your issue in mongoose since you didn't indicate you want to match any criteria on the `Transaction` Model. You could format the date into the sample you used in your question.

```
Transaction.aggregate([
  { 
     "$addFields": {
        "createdDate": {
           $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$createdDate" }
        }
     }
  },
  { 
     "$group": {
        "_id": { "$createdDate" },
        "transactions": {
            "$push": "$$ROOT"
        }
     }
  }])
```

These are a few references from the mongodb doc site to help you understand the aggregation better.

[DateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html) , [Group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html), [Push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/index.html)

And I also suggest you use [mongodb documentation site](https://docs.mongodb.com/) for most of your references as it has a lot of useful information to help you easily understand the concepts.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out. I really don't need to convert a date into a string. I just wrote that for example. I want the date to be as it is (A Timestamp)