# Mongodb select query with "date" from "timestamp" field

Tags: mongodb

We are using "timestamp" field on our documents but we want to select document with "date".
Is it possible ?

```
"track":{
          "trackSourceList":[
             {
                "sourceId":"45",
                "sourceType":"AIS_CLASS_A",
                "trackId":"45271042797"
             }
          ],
          "battleSpaceObject":{
             "shipName":"xxx",
             "callSign":"xxx",
             "shipType":{
                "_id":"999600000000000000166",
                "shipStatCode5":{
                   "_id":"999600000000000000519",
                   "shipStatCode5":"B34E2SV",
                   "editable":false
                },
                "shipTypeValue":"OTHER",
                "aisShipType":"UNKNOWN",
                "editable":false
             },
             "flag":"xxx",
             "imoNo":"0",
             "mmsiNo":"271042797",
             "lengthOverall":18,
             "breadth":4,
             "pursuitShipList":[
                
             ],
             "shipAttachmentList":[
                
             ],
             "shipRegistry":{
                
             },
             "isPursuitShipIndicator":false
          },
          "trackKinematic":{
             "trackLat":41.11355972290039,
             "trackLon":29.056987762451172,
             "trackAlt":0,
             "groundSpeed":0,
             "course":215.10000610351562,
             "turnRate":0,
             "trackQuality":"NULL",
             "timeStamp":{
                "$numberLong":"1608882200099"
```

We want to select data using "date" data type by "track.trackKinematic.timeStamp".

Can anyone help us?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert timestamp to date in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024852/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-in-mongodb)

Comment: Actually i can convert to timestamp to date. But i didn't do what i want. 
I think i need compound query. First convert to "timestamp" to "date" and then search the database with "date" field. That why i copied my document example.

Also i tried link you sent. It doesn't work or i did some mistake. I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Since version of mongodb is not provided in your question's context, you can try the following two ways.

The process involves projecting the long type to date type first and then adding a match stage to get the documents.

1. MongoDB < 4.0
   Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "longToDateField": {
        "$add": [
          new Date(0),
          "$track.trackKinematic.timeStamp"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "longToDateField": ISODate("2020-12-25T07:43:20.099Z")
    }
  }
])
```

2. MongoDB 4.0
   Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "longToDateField": {
        "$toDate": "$track.trackKinematic.timeStamp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "longToDateField": ISODate("2020-12-25T07:43:20.099Z")
    }
  }
])
```

But, why don't you just convert the search date to long and then query the documents.
That should be fairly simple and I believe all programming languages support this type of conversion.

Comment: Our mongo version is 4.2. I executed second query but no result :(

I told our developer team to add a new date field and convert to date from timestamp.